# Handling large XML file in iphone app

Tags: iphone, xml, memory-management

I have to make an iphone app for some customer.

He should be able to add some data to the app using a HTML form that update an XML file.

So I think this XML file may contain over 1000 item by the time.

Is that normal or should I work with other data storage techniques?

The XML file is used to display some information in UITableView.

Comment: What is this XML file used for? It is displayed in a UITableView for instance?

Comment: yes, Sorry I forgot to mention it.

Comment: Let me guess: some sort of catalog with a master/details type view? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1000 items doesn't seem like a lot if it's simple textual information.

I worked on an application that displayed several hundreds of complex items using UITableViews on a 1st gen iPad, the amount of data pulled from the webservice was never a problem. The problem I faced was scrolling performance and proper cell reuse.

Of course, you have to be rigorous with memory management if you expect a lot of data to be displayed in your app, else leaks will very quickly make your app crash.

Comment: No pb :) If you're really concerned, you could try to guesstimate the amount of memory each item will use, then compare vs the amount your app can use on the device.